# How do I assign strings to an array list with error message "Non Static method reference Static Context"?

Tags: java, database, static

//Start of Address.java

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class Address
{    
    String firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zip;
    public void Address()
    {
        firstname = new String();
        lastname = new String();
        street = new String();
        city = new String();
        state = new String();
        zip = new String();
    }

    public void setFirstname(String v)
    {
        firstname = v;
    }

    public String getFirstname()
    {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String v)
    {
        lastname = v;
    }

    public String getLastname()
    {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setStreet(String v)
    {
        street = v;
    }

    public String getStreet()
    {
        return street;
    }

    public void setState(String v)
    {
        state = v;
    }

    public String getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public void setCity(String v)
    {
        city = v;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setZip(String v)
    {
        zip = v;
    }

    public String getZip()
    {
        return zip;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String empty = "";
        if ((firstname == null) || empty.equals(firstname)) {
            street = "<em>(no firstname specified)</em>";
        }
        if ((lastname == null) || empty.equals(lastname)) {
            street = "<em>(no lastname specified)</em>";
        }
        if ((street == null) || empty.equals(street)) {
            street = "<em>(no street specified)</em>";
        }
        if ((city == null) || empty.equals(city)) {
            city = "<em>(no city specified)</em>";
        }
        if ((state == null) || empty.equals(state)) {
            state = "<em>(no state specified)</em>";
        } else {
            int abbrevIndex = state.indexOf('(') + 1;
            state = state.substring(abbrevIndex,
                                    abbrevIndex + 2);
        }
        if ((zip == null) || empty.equals(zip)) {
            zip = "";
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("<html><p align=center>");
        sb.append(firstname);
        sb.append("&nbsp;");
        sb.append(lastname);
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append(street);
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append(city);
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(state); //should format
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(zip);
        sb.append("</p></html>");
        return sb.toString();
      }
    }
// End of Address.java

//Start of AddressBook.java

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * AddressBook.java uses these additional files:
 *   SpringUtilities.java
 *   ...
 */

public class AddressBook extends JPanel
                                          implements ActionListener,
                                                     FocusListener {
    Address address;
    // make the List in java.util to distinguish it from the List definition in java.swing
    java.util.List<Address> addresslist = new ArrayList<>();    //The text field controls in the user interface
    JTextField firstnameField,lastnameField,streetField, cityField;
    JFormattedTextField zipField;
    // a spinner control that holds the state names
    JSpinner stateSpinner;
    boolean addressSet = false;
    Font regularFont, italicFont;
    JLabel addressDisplay;
    final static int GAP = 10;

    public AddressBook() { 
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));    
        JPanel leftHalf = new JPanel() {
            //Don't allow us to stretch vertically.
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                Dimension pref = getPreferredSize();
                return new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                     pref.height);
            }
        };
        leftHalf.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftHalf,
                                         BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        leftHalf.add(createEntryFields());
        leftHalf.add(createButtons());    
        add(leftHalf);
        add(createAddressDisplay());            
    }

    protected JComponent createButtons() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));    
        JButton button = new JButton("Save name and address");    
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button);    
        button = new JButton("Clear address");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setActionCommand("clear");
        panel.add(button);    
        //Match the SpringLayout's gap, subtracting 5 to make
        //up for the default gap FlowLayout provides.
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0,
                                                GAP-5, GAP-5));
        return panel;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the button or presses
     * Enter in a text field.
     */

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("clear".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            addressSet = false;
            firstnameField.setText("");
            lastnameField.setText("");
            streetField.setText("");
            cityField.setText("");    
            //We can't just setText on the formatted text
            //field, since its value will remain set.
            zipField.setValue(null);
        } else {
            addressSet = true;
        }
        addAddress();
        updateDisplays();
    }

    protected void updateDisplays() {
        addressDisplay.setText(formatAddress());
        if (addressSet) {
            addressDisplay.setFont(regularFont);
        } else {
            addressDisplay.setFont(italicFont);
        }
    }

    protected JComponent createAddressDisplay() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        addressDisplay = new JLabel();
        addressDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        regularFont = addressDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,
                                                            16.0f);
        italicFont = regularFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
        updateDisplays();    
        //Lay out the panel.
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                GAP/2, //top
                                0,     //left
                                GAP/2, //bottom
                                0));   //right
        panel.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL),
                  BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        panel.add(addressDisplay,
                  BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));    
        return panel;
    }

    protected void addAddress()
    {    
        Addresslist.add(Address.getFirstname());
        Addresslist.add();
        Address.getLastname();
        Address.getStreet();
        Address.getCity();
        Address.getZip();           
    }

    protected String formatAddress() {
        if (!addressSet) return "No address set.";    
        return address.toString();
    }

    //A convenience method for creating a MaskFormatter.
    protected MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
            System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return formatter;
    }

    /**
     * Called when one of the fields gets the focus so that
     * we can select the focused field.
     */
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        Component c = e.getComponent();
        if (c instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
            selectItLater(c);
        } else if (c instanceof JTextField) {
            ((JTextField)c).selectAll();
        }
    }

    //Workaround for formatted text field focus side effects.
    protected void selectItLater(Component c) {
        if (c instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
            final JFormattedTextField ftf = (JFormattedTextField)c;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ftf.selectAll();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //Needed for FocusListener interface.
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) { } //ignore    
    protected JComponent createEntryFields() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());    
        String[] labelStrings = {
            "First","Last",
            "Street address: ",
            "City: ",
            "State: ",
            "Zip code: "
        };    
        JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[labelStrings.length];
        JComponent[] fields = new JComponent[labelStrings.length];
        int fieldNum = 0;    
        //Create the text field and set it up.
        firstnameField  = new JTextField();
        firstnameField.setColumns(20);
        fields[fieldNum++] = firstnameField;    
        lastnameField  = new JTextField();
        lastnameField.setColumns(20);
        fields[fieldNum++] = lastnameField;    
        streetField  = new JTextField();
        streetField.setColumns(20);
        fields[fieldNum++] = streetField;    
        cityField = new JTextField();
        cityField.setColumns(20);
        fields[fieldNum++] = cityField;    
        String[] stateStrings = getStateStrings();
        stateSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerListModel(stateStrings));
        fields[fieldNum++] = stateSpinner;    
        zipField = new JFormattedTextField(
                            createFormatter("#####"));
        fields[fieldNum++] = zipField;    
        //Associate label/field pairs, add everything,
        //and lay it out.
        for (int i = 0; i < labelStrings.length; i++) {
            labels[i] = new JLabel(labelStrings[i],
                                   JLabel.TRAILING);
            labels[i].setLabelFor(fields[i]);
            panel.add(labels[i]);
            panel.add(fields[i]);    
            //Add listeners to each field.
            JTextField tf = null;
            if (fields[i] instanceof JSpinner) {
                tf = getTextField((JSpinner)fields[i]);
            } else {
                tf = (JTextField)fields[i];
            }
            tf.addActionListener(this);
            tf.addFocusListener(this);
        }
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel,
                                        labelStrings.length, 2,
                                        GAP, GAP, //init x,y
                                        GAP, GAP/2);//xpad, ypad
        return panel;
    }

    public String[] getStateStrings() {
        String[] stateStrings = {
            "Alabama (AL)",
            "Alaska (AK)",
            "Arizona (AZ)",
            "Arkansas (AR)",
            "California (CA)",
            "Colorado (CO)",
            "Connecticut (CT)",
            "Delaware (DE)",
            "District of Columbia (DC)",
            "Florida (FL)",
            "Georgia (GA)",
            "Hawaii (HI)",
            "Idaho (ID)",
            "Illinois (IL)",
            "Indiana (IN)",
            "Iowa (IA)",
            "Kansas (KS)",
            "Kentucky (KY)",
            "Louisiana (LA)",
            "Maine (ME)",
            "Maryland (MD)",
            "Massachusetts (MA)",
            "Michigan (MI)",
            "Minnesota (MN)",
            "Mississippi (MS)",
            "Missouri (MO)",
            "Montana (MT)",
            "Nebraska (NE)",
            "Nevada (NV)",
            "New Hampshire (NH)",
            "New Jersey (NJ)",
            "New Mexico (NM)",
            "New York (NY)",
            "North Carolina (NC)",
            "North Dakota (ND)",
            "Ohio (OH)",
            "Oklahoma (OK)",
            "Oregon (OR)",
            "Pennsylvania (PA)",
            "Rhode Island (RI)",
            "South Carolina (SC)",
            "South Dakota (SD)",
            "Tennessee (TN)",
            "Texas (TX)",
            "Utah (UT)",
            "Vermont (VT)",
            "Virginia (VA)",
            "Washington (WA)",
            "West Virginia (WV)",
            "Wisconsin (WI)",
            "Wyoming (WY)"
        };
        return stateStrings;
    }

    public JFormattedTextField getTextField(JSpinner spinner) {
        JComponent editor = spinner.getEditor();
        if (editor instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor) {
            return ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)editor).getTextField();
        } else {
            System.err.println("Unexpected editor type: "
                               + spinner.getEditor().getClass()
                               + " isn't a descendant of DefaultEditor");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Address Book");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new AddressBook());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
                System.out.println(addresslist);
            }
        });
    }
}
// End of AddressBook.java

//Start of SpringUtilities.java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * A 1.4 file that provides utility methods for
 * creating form- or grid-style layouts with SpringLayout.
 * These utilities are used by several programs, such as
 * SpringBox and SpringCompactGrid.
 */
public class SpringUtilities {
    /**
     * A debugging utility that prints to stdout the component's
     * minimum, preferred, and maximum sizes.
     */
    public static void printSizes(Component c) {
        System.out.println("minimumSize = " + c.getMinimumSize());
        System.out.println("preferredSize = " + c.getPreferredSize());
        System.out.println("maximumSize = " + c.getMaximumSize());
    }

    /**
     * Aligns the first <code>rows</code> * <code>cols</code>
     * components of <code>parent</code> in
     * a grid. Each component is as big as the maximum
     * preferred width and height of the components.
     * The parent is made just big enough to fit them all.
     *
     * @param rows number of rows
     * @param cols number of columns
     * @param initialX x location to start the grid at
     * @param initialY y location to start the grid at
     * @param xPad x padding between cells
     * @param yPad y padding between cells
     */
    public static void makeGrid(Container parent,
                                int rows, int cols,
                                int initialX, int initialY,
                                int xPad, int yPad) {
        SpringLayout layout;
        try {
            layout = (SpringLayout)parent.getLayout();
        } catch (ClassCastException exc) {
            System.err.println("The first argument to makeGrid must use SpringLayout.");
            return;
        }    
        Spring xPadSpring = Spring.constant(xPad);
        Spring yPadSpring = Spring.constant(yPad);
        Spring initialXSpring = Spring.constant(initialX);
        Spring initialYSpring = Spring.constant(initialY);
        int max = rows * cols;    
        //Calculate Springs that are the max of the width/height so that all
        //cells have the same size.
        Spring maxWidthSpring = layout.getConstraints(parent.getComponent(0)).
                                    getWidth();
        Spring maxHeightSpring = layout.getConstraints(parent.getComponent(0)).
                                    getWidth();
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            SpringLayout.Constraints cons = layout.getConstraints(
                                            parent.getComponent(i));    
            maxWidthSpring = Spring.max(maxWidthSpring, cons.getWidth());
            maxHeightSpring = Spring.max(maxHeightSpring, cons.getHeight());
        }

        //Apply the new width/height Spring. This forces all the
        //components to have the same size.
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            SpringLayout.Constraints cons = layout.getConstraints(
                                            parent.getComponent(i));    
            cons.setWidth(maxWidthSpring);
            cons.setHeight(maxHeightSpring);
        }

        //Then adjust the x/y constraints of all the cells so that they
        //are aligned in a grid.
        SpringLayout.Constraints lastCons = null;
        SpringLayout.Constraints lastRowCons = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            SpringLayout.Constraints cons = layout.getConstraints(
                                                 parent.getComponent(i));
            if (i % cols == 0) { //start of new row
                lastRowCons = lastCons;
                cons.setX(initialXSpring);
            } else { //x position depends on previous component
                cons.setX(Spring.sum(lastCons.getConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST),
                                     xPadSpring));
            }

            if (i / cols == 0) { //first row
                cons.setY(initialYSpring);
            } else { //y position depends on previous row
                cons.setY(Spring.sum(lastRowCons.getConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH),
                                     yPadSpring));
            }
            lastCons = cons;
        }

        //Set the parent's size.
        SpringLayout.Constraints pCons = layout.getConstraints(parent);
        pCons.setConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,
                            Spring.sum(
                                Spring.constant(yPad),
                                lastCons.getConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH)));
        pCons.setConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,
                            Spring.sum(
                                Spring.constant(xPad),
                                lastCons.getConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST)));
    }

    /* Used by makeCompactGrid. */
    private static SpringLayout.Constraints getConstraintsForCell(
                                                int row, int col,
                                                Container parent,
                                                int cols) {
        SpringLayout layout = (SpringLayout) parent.getLayout();
        Component c = parent.getComponent(row * cols + col);
        return layout.getConstraints(c);
    }

    /**
     * Aligns the first <code>rows</code> * <code>cols</code>
     * components of <code>parent</code> in
     * a grid. Each component in a column is as wide as the maximum
     * preferred width of the components in that column;
     * height is similarly determined for each row.
     * The parent is made just big enough to fit them all.
     *
     * @param rows number of rows
     * @param cols number of columns
     * @param initialX x location to start the grid at
     * @param initialY y location to start the grid at
     * @param xPad x padding between cells
     * @param yPad y padding between cells
     */
    public static void makeCompactGrid(Container parent,
                                       int rows, int cols,
                                       int initialX, int initialY,
                                       int xPad, int yPad) {
        SpringLayout layout;
        try {
            layout = (SpringLayout)parent.getLayout();
        } catch (ClassCastException exc) {
            System.err.println("The first argument to makeCompactGrid must use SpringLayout.");
            return;
        }

        //Align all cells in each column and make them the same width.
        Spring x = Spring.constant(initialX);
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            Spring width = Spring.constant(0);
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                width = Spring.max(width,
                                   getConstraintsForCell(r, c, parent, cols).
                                       getWidth());
            }
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                SpringLayout.Constraints constraints =
                        getConstraintsForCell(r, c, parent, cols);
                constraints.setX(x);
                constraints.setWidth(width);
            }
            x = Spring.sum(x, Spring.sum(width, Spring.constant(xPad)));
        }

        //Align all cells in each row and make them the same height.
        Spring y = Spring.constant(initialY);
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            Spring height = Spring.constant(0);
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                height = Spring.max(height,
                                    getConstraintsForCell(r, c, parent, cols).
                                        getHeight());
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                SpringLayout.Constraints constraints =
                        getConstraintsForCell(r, c, parent, cols);
                constraints.setY(y);
                constraints.setHeight(height);
            }
            y = Spring.sum(y, Spring.sum(height, Spring.constant(yPad)));
        }

        //Set the parent's size.
        SpringLayout.Constraints pCons = layout.getConstraints(parent);
        pCons.setConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, y);
        pCons.setConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, x);
    }
}
//End of SpringUtilities.java
```

So I am confused on how to implement the AddAddress() method in accordance with a ArrayList. The error the terminal is giving me is "Non Static method cannot be referenced by Static Context". Please any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been searching for a while on what to do but it only confuses me more. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, this is way to much code. Boil your code down to a minimum, so that it still contains the error. Then it will be easy to fix. Or search for exact that error message, many similar problems have been solved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem (possibly unrelated) is that your constructor is returning type void:

```
public void Address()
{
    firstname = new String();
    lastname = new String();
    street = new String();
    city = new String();
    state = new String();
    zip = new String();
}
```

This should be:

```
public Address() {
    firstname = new String();
    lastname = new String();
    street = new String();
    city = new String();
    state = new String();
    zip = new String();
}
```

Comment: `code`  String State = (String)stateSpinner.getValue();
        address = new Address();
        address.firstname = (firstnameField.getText());
        address.lastname = (lastnameField.getText());
        address.street = (streetField.getText());
        address.city= (cityField.getText());
        address.zip = (zipField.getText());
        address.state = State;
        addresslist.add(address); `code` I ended up doing this. Sorry I don't know how to properly format this.

Comment: Sorry that this is three years later... But, all you need to do is remove the word 'void' from this method to turn it into a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to access non existing static methods Address.xxx ...
change Address (uppercase A) to address (lowercase a).

also, you add the whole address instance to the list:

```
    protected void addAddress()
    {    
         addresslist.add(address);
    }
```